# alternative to cvWaitKey() function in iOS

Tags: ios, opencv

ok, what i am trying to do is retrieve a frame from an existing video file, do some work on the frame and then save it to a new file,

what actually happens is that it writes some frames and then crashes as the code is quite fast,
if i don't put cvWaitKey() i get the same error i get when writing video frames with AVFoundation Library without using

```
AVAssetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData
```

OpenCV video writer is implemented using AVFoundation classes but we lose access to

```
AVAssetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData
```

or am i missing something ?

here is the code similar to what i'm trying to do,

```
while (grabResult&&frameResult) {

        grabResult = cvGrabFrame(capture);          // capture a frame
        if(grabResult){
            img = cvRetrieveFrame(capture, 0);  // retrieve the captured frame
            cvFlip(img,NULL,0);                 // edit img
            frameResult = cvWriteFrame(writer,img);      // add the frame to the file
            cvWaitKey(-1); or anything that helps to finish adding the previous frame
        }
    }
```

> I am trying to convert a video file using OpenCV (without displaying)
>   in my iPhone/iPad app, everything works except cvWaitKey() function
>   and I get this error:
>
> ```
> OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvWaitKey,
> ```
>
> Without this function frames are dropped as there's no way to know if
>   the video writer is ready, is there an alternative to my problem?
>
> I am using OpenCV 2.4.2 and I get same error with the latest
>   precompiled version of OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about iOS development, but did you try calling the C++ interface method [`waitKey()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=waitkey#waitkey)?

Answer (score 0):

Repaint the `UIImageView`:

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.0f]];
```

followed by your `imshow` or `cvShowImage`